# RDC to Vista without logging out current user

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop

At home, I have a desktop with Windows Vista Home Premium. I share it with one more person. While this other person is logged on and working on something, I am able to connect, from my laptop, with RDC to desktop and we are both logged on desktop working at the same time.

At office, we have Vista Ultimate PCs in a domain, but I am unable to connect with RDC to another PC without logging off the other user.

I can't figure out what have I configured on my home system to be able to make this possible in the office. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you logging in as a different user at home, but the same user at work?

Comment: as different user in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that you are referring to is only available on the Server
versions of Windows. That feature is not available in Vista (a client version), unless one were to resort to 'hacking' it in.

The following article supposedly shows how this is done:
[How to enable multiple remote desktop sessions on XP or Vista](http://remotedesktoprdp.com/Multiple-Remote-Desktop-Sessions.aspx)

Some words of caution:

1. Create a system restore point before
   starting, to which you can go back
   if it doesn't work.
2. This hack involves downloading and installing hacked system files, which is always risky.

Comment: this is it, just have to watchout for version of termsrv.dll, if you have Service Pack 1 installed, version is different etc. I've installed Win 7 now, and found same hack.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for only exists in the Server line of Windows, such as Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008.

Windows Vista Home Premium doesn't support remote desktop server at all, so I think you may be mistaken about what OS you are running at home, or you have installed a third party hack to enable the functionality.

Comment: C:\Users\Andrija>ver Output:
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6001]

Comment: System info says: Windows Vista Home Premium

Comment: You probably installed a hack such as this: http://www.unet.fi/fransblog/2007/08/30/enable-remote-desktop-connection-on-vista-home-premium/

Answer (score -1):

You're probably using Remote Assistance at home.  Since it's a help desk service, it has 2 main differences from Remote Desktop Connection:

- Local user must confirm incoming connection
- Local user shares screen with connected user

[What is the difference between Remote Desktop Connection and Windows Remote Assistance?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-the-difference-between-Remote-Desktop-Connection-and-Windows-Remote-Assistance)